# JQuery Multi Step Form - Go back to first step once close

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

How can I go back to the first of my multi-step form once the modal is closed?

I managed to reset the percentage to its original number, but not the form.

**Here's my Multi-step JavaScript** :

```
/**
* Created by admin on 20/05/2017.
*/
$(document).ready(function(){
var current = 1;

widget      = $(".step");
btnnext     = $(".next");
btnback     = $(".back");
btnsubmit   = $(".submit");

// Init buttons and UI
widget.not(':eq(0)').hide();
hideButtons(current);
setProgress(current);

// Next button click action
btnnext.click(function(){
    if(current < widget.length){
        // Check validation
        if($("#register-form").valid()){
            widget.show();
            widget.not(':eq('+(current++)+')').hide();
            setProgress(current);
        }
    }
    hideButtons(current);
});

// Back button click action
btnback.click(function(){
    if(current > 1){
        current = current - 2;
        if(current < widget.length){
            widget.show();
            widget.not(':eq('+(current++)+')').hide();
            setProgress(current);
        }
    }
    hideButtons(current);
})
```

});

```
// Change progress bar action
setProgress = function(currstep){
var percent = parseFloat(100 / widget.length) * currstep;
/*
 * 100/TheNumberOfWidget * TheCurrentOne
 * If we remove the current one (currstep), the progress bar won't increase.
 */
percent = percent.toFixed();
$(".progress-bar").css("width",percent+"%").html(percent+"%");
// Simply show % in the progress-bar class.
```

};

```
// Hide buttons according to the current step
hideButtons = function(current){
var limit = parseInt(widget.length);
/*
 * limit = The nubmer of the widget, and it is a integer value.
 */

$(".action").hide();
// Hide the buttons

if(current < limit) btnnext.show();
/*
 * If there is at least one widget after the current one :
 * it will show next
 */
if(current > 1) btnback.show();
/*
 * If there is at least one widget before the current one :
 * it will show back
 */
if (current === limit) {
    // Show entered values when we reached the the last widget form.
    $(".display label:not(.control-label)").each(function(){
        console.log($(this).parent().find("label:not(.control-label)").html($("#"+$(this).data("id")).val()));
    });
    btnnext.hide();
    btnsubmit.show();
}
};
```

**Here is my form**

```
    <!-- Modal Register -->
<div class="modal fade modal-ext modal-register" id="modal-register" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
     aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
     aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <!-- Modal Register | Container -->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <!-- Modal Register | Form-->
            <form method="post" role="form" id="register-form" autocomplete="off">
                <!-- Modal Register | Title -->
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Sign up</h4>
                </div>
                <!--/.Modal Register | Title -->

                <!-- Modal Register | Content -->
                <div class="modal-body">

                    <!-- json response will be here -->
                    <div id="error_register"></div>
                    <!-- json response will be here -->


                    <div class="progress">
                        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-custom progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar"
                             aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Modal Register | Firstname -->
                    <div class="step">
                        <br>
                        <div class="md-form modal_md_form">
                            <i class="fa fa-user prefix"></i>
                            <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" class="form-control" required>
                            <label for="firstname">Firstname</label>
                            <span class="help-block" id="error"></span>
                        </div>

                        <!-- Modal Register | Lastname -->
                        <div class="md-form modal_md_form">
                            <i class="fa fa-circle prefix"></i>
                            <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" class="form-control" required>
                            <label for="lastname">Lastname</label>
                            <span class="help-block" id="error"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Modal Register | Username -->
                    <div class="step">
                        <br>
                        <div class="md-form modal_md_form">
                            <i class="fa fa-user prefix"></i>
                            <input type="text" id="username" name="username" class="form-control" required>
                            <label for="username">Username</label>
                            <span class="help-block" id="error"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Modal Register | Password -->
                    <div class="step">
                        <br>
                        <div class="md-form modal_md_form">
                            <i class="fa fa-lock prefix"></i>
                            <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control" required>
                            <label for="password">Password</label>
                            <span class="help-block" id="error"></span>
                        </div>

                        <!-- Modal Register | Retype Password -->
                        <div class="md-form modal_md_form">
                            <i class="fa fa-asterisk prefix"></i>
                            <input type="password" id="cpassword" name="cpassword" class="form-control" required>
                            <label for="cpassword">Retype Password</label>
                            <span class="help-block" id="error"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Modal Register | Email -->
                    <div class="step">
                        <br>
                        <div class="md-form modal_md_form">
                            <i class="fa fa-envelope prefix"></i>
                            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="form-control"
                                   pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+">
                            <label for="email">Mail</label>
                            <span class="help-block" id="error"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Modal Login | Check -->
                    <?php
                    $number_a = rand(1, 5);
                    $number_b = rand(0, 4);
                    $_SESSION['register_valid_operation'] = $number_a + $number_b;
                    ?>
                    <div class="step">
                        <br>
                        <div class="md-form modal_md_form">
                        <i class="fa fa-calculator prefix"></i>
                        <input type="text" id="register_result" name="register_result" class="form-control" required>
                        <label for="register_result"><?php echo($number_a) ?> + <?php echo($number_b) ?> = ?</label>
                        <span class="help-block" id="error"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div class="step display">
                        <h5>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Confirm details</h5>
                        <br>
                        <div class="modal_md_form">
                            <div>
                                <label class="col-xs-2 control-label">Firstname</label>
                                <div class="col-xs-10">
                                    <label data-id="firstname"></label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal_md_form">
                            <label class="col-xs-2 control-label">Lastname</label>
                            <div class="col-xs-10">
                                <label data-id="lastname"></label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal_md_form">
                            <label class="col-xs-2 control-label">Username</label>
                            <div class="col-xs-10">
                                <label data-id="username"></label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal_md_form">
                            <label class="col-xs-2 control-label">Email</label>
                            <div class="col-xs-10">
                                <label data-id="email"></label>
                                <br><br>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Modal Register | Send -->
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <div class="pull-left">
                                <button type="button" class="action back btn btn-primary">Back</button>
                                <button type="button" class="action next btn btn-primary">Next</button>
                                <button class="action submit btn btn-primary" id="btn-signup">Submit</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!--/.Modal Register | Content -->

                <!--Footer-->
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </form>
            <!--/.Modal Register | Form-->
        </div>
        <!--/.Modal Register | Container -->
    </div>
</div>
<!--/ Modal Register -->
```

**Here is my script to close the modal, reset it and reset the progress bar :**

```
$('#modal-register').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
var current = 1;
$("#register-form").trigger('reset');
setProgress(current);
});
```

How can I make it to reset the form to the step 1 (Firstname & Lastname)?

Comment: I d'ont understand your question, you want to reset your form and go back to the first step, but you have this answer on your question : $('#yourForm').reset() and current = 0, btnnext.trigger('click'), so what I missed in your question ?

Comment: I mean, when you fill in the information in the modal form, you have several step separated by a "back" and "next" button.

Once you close the modal, I'd like the form to go back to the first step nth:child(1) precisely where Firstname and Username are.

The form resets already, but it doesn't go back to that step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying your code, I think you get the wrong close button.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var current = 1;

    widget = $(".step");
    btnnext = $(".next");
    btnback = $(".back");
    btnsubmit = $(".submit");
    btnclose = $(".btn-default");

    // Init buttons and UI
    widget.not(':eq(0)').hide();
    hideButtons(current);
    setProgress(current);

    // Next button click action
    btnnext.click(function () {
        if (current < widget.length) {
            // Check validation
            //if ($("#register-form").valid()) {
                widget.show();
                widget.not(':eq(' + (current++) + ')').hide();
                setProgress(current);
            //}
        }
        hideButtons(current);
    });

    // Back button click action
    btnback.click(function () {
        if (current > 1) {
            current = current - 2;
            if (current < widget.length) {
                widget.show();
                widget.not(':eq(' + (current++) + ')').hide();
                setProgress(current);
            }
        }
        hideButtons(current);
    });
    
    btnclose.on("click", function() {
        current = 0;
        $("#register-form").trigger("reset");
        btnnext.trigger("click");
    });
});

// Change progress bar action
var setProgress = function (currstep) {
    var percent = parseFloat(100 / widget.length) * currstep;
    /*
     * 100/TheNumberOfWidget * TheCurrentOne
     * If we remove the current one (currstep), the progress bar won't increase.
     */
    percent = percent.toFixed();
    $(".progress-bar").css("width", percent + "%").html(percent + "%");
    // Simply show % in the progress-bar class.
};

// Hide buttons according to the current step
var hideButtons = function (current) {
    var limit = parseInt(widget.length);
    /*
     * limit = The nubmer of the widget, and it is a integer value.
     */

    $(".action").hide();
    // Hide the buttons

    if (current < limit) btnnext.show();
    /*
     * If there is at least one widget after the current one :
     * it will show next
     */
    if (current > 1) btnback.show();
    /*
     * If there is at least one widget before the current one :
     * it will show back
     */
    if (current === limit) {
        btnnext.hide();
        btnsubmit.show();
    }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal fade modal-ext modal-register" id="modal-register" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
     aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
     aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <!-- Modal Register | Container -->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <!-- Modal Register | Form-->
            <form method="post" role="form" id="register-form" autocomplete="off">
                <!-- Modal Register | Title -->
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Sign up</h4>
                </div>
                <!--/.Modal Register | Title -->

                <!-- Modal Register | Content -->
                <div class="modal-body">

                    <!-- json response will be here -->
                    <div id="error_register"></div>
                    <!-- json response will be here -->


                    <div class="progress">
                        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-custom progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar"
                             aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Modal Register | Firstname -->
                    <div class="step">
                        <br>
                        <div class="md-form modal_md_form">
                            <i class="fa fa-user prefix"></i>
                            <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" class="form-control" required>
                            <label for="firstname">Firstname</label>
                            <span class="help-block" id="error"></span>
                        </div>

                        <!-- Modal Register | Lastname -->
                        <div class="md-form modal_md_form">
                            <i class="fa fa-circle prefix"></i>
                            <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" class="form-control" required>
                            <label for="lastname">Lastname</label>
                            <span class="help-block" id="error"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Modal Register | Username -->
                    <div class="step">
                        <br>
                        <div class="md-form modal_md_form">
                            <i class="fa fa-user prefix"></i>
                            <input type="text" id="username" name="username" class="form-control" required>
                            <label for="username">Username</label>
                            <span class="help-block" id="error"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Modal Register | Password -->
                    <div class="step">
                        <br>
                        <div class="md-form modal_md_form">
                            <i class="fa fa-lock prefix"></i>
                            <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control" required>
                            <label for="password">Password</label>
                            <span class="help-block" id="error"></span>
                        </div>

                        <!-- Modal Register | Retype Password -->
                        <div class="md-form modal_md_form">
                            <i class="fa fa-asterisk prefix"></i>
                            <input type="password" id="cpassword" name="cpassword" class="form-control" required>
                            <label for="cpassword">Retype Password</label>
                            <span class="help-block" id="error"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Modal Register | Email -->
                    <div class="step">
                        <br>
                        <div class="md-form modal_md_form">
                            <i class="fa fa-envelope prefix"></i>
                            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="form-control"
                                   pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+">
                            <label for="email">Mail</label>
                            <span class="help-block" id="error"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="step">
                        <br>
                        <div class="md-form modal_md_form">
                        <i class="fa fa-calculator prefix"></i>
                        <input type="text" id="register_result" name="register_result" class="form-control" required>
                        <label for="register_result"><?php echo($number_a) ?> + <?php echo($number_b) ?> = ?</label>
                        <span class="help-block" id="error"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div class="step display">
                        <h5>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Confirm details</h5>
                        <br>
                        <div class="modal_md_form">
                            <div>
                                <label class="col-xs-2 control-label">Firstname</label>
                                <div class="col-xs-10">
                                    <label data-id="firstname"></label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal_md_form">
                            <label class="col-xs-2 control-label">Lastname</label>
                            <div class="col-xs-10">
                                <label data-id="lastname"></label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal_md_form">
                            <label class="col-xs-2 control-label">Username</label>
                            <div class="col-xs-10">
                                <label data-id="username"></label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal_md_form">
                            <label class="col-xs-2 control-label">Email</label>
                            <div class="col-xs-10">
                                <label data-id="email"></label>
                                <br><br>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Modal Register | Send -->
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <div class="pull-left">
                                <button type="button" class="action back btn btn-primary">Back</button>
                                <button type="button" class="action next btn btn-primary">Next</button>
                                <button class="action submit btn btn-primary" id="btn-signup">Submit</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!--/.Modal Register | Content -->

                <!--Footer-->
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </form>
            <!--/.Modal Register | Form-->
        </div>
        <!--/.Modal Register | Container -->
    </div>
</div>
```